# Check a folder is exist or not

Tags: objective-c, ios

Has someone work with this method of NSFileManager ?

```
- (BOOL)fileExistsAtPath:(NSString *)path isDirectory:(BOOL *)isDirectory;
```

How can I use this method to check a folder is existing or not ?

Comment: What is your question exactly ?

Comment: there should be thousands of answers just saying "Yes!" now.

Comment: Yes I have. Next question please..!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NSFileManager`'s `fileExistsAtPath:isDirectory:` method.  See Apple's docs [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/fileExistsAtPath%3aisDirectory%3a).

or based on your example you could use the following as well

Take a look in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/fileExistsAtPath%3aisDirectory%3a) for this method signature:

```
- (BOOL)fileExistsAtPath:(NSString *)path isDirectory:(BOOL *)isDirectory
```

You need a pointer to a BOOL var as argument, not a BOOL itself. NSFileManager will record if the file is a directory or not in that variable. For example:

```
BOOL isDir;
BOOL exists = [fm fileExistsAtPath:path isDirectory:&isDir];
if (exists) {
    /* file exists */
    if (isDir) {
        /* file is a directory */
    }
 }
```

Also 
Start by understanding Low-Level File Management Programming Topics

1) NSFileManager [currentDirectoryPath](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/currentDirectoryPath)

3) NSFileManager [fileExistsAtPath:isDirectory:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: This is the same method that he posted in the question.

Comment: Ramy take a closer look and you will see that it's different.. not sure what you are looking at...

Comment: the «Introduction to Low-Level File Management Programming Topics» link is dead

Comment: Corrected the link by removing ...sorry

Comment: Basically you're answering to a non-question, he has aked if someone has worked with the fileExistsAtPath:isDirectory: method, and you answered saying to use that method.

Comment: 6 of 1/2 Dozen of the other..I know he didn't ask a real question but being that I have looked deeper into what he's probably wanting , I think that I have provided him an adequate answer if not a good point of reference to start learning things from a basic System.IO perspective..

Comment: BTW: usually after `1)` the next number is `2)`

Comment: I am in the middle of answering a Reflection Question so not sure what you are talking about..

Comment: Im trying to use this method. but I see it's weird and just want to ask there are anyone using this method can help me.